# AMC Grade 10 Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The question:

> $a,b,c$ are three real numbers, where  $a= b + \sqrt 2$, and  $2ab + 2\sqrt 2 c^2 +1 = 0$. Find $a+b+c$

Comment: @Silverleaf1 I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, if you need to solve a problem in real variables when you're given fewer equations than variables, you likely need to show a sum of squares is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$2\left(b+\sqrt{2}\right)b+\sqrt{8}c^{2}+1=0$$
$$\left(b+\sqrt{2}\right)b+\sqrt{2}c^{2}+1=0$$

$$b^{2}+\sqrt{2}b+\left(\sqrt{2}c^{2}+1\right)=0$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the solutions, I tried several times and focus on the (a+b+c)

Answer (score 0):

You should always show your attempts, even if you haven't got very far or you're not satisfied with your work.

Substitute $a$ in the second equation to get:

$$2b(b+\sqrt{2})+2\sqrt{2}c^2+1=0$$

or equivalently

$$2\left(b+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2+2\sqrt{2}c^2=0$$

This implies that $b=-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\ c = 0$ and then $a=\sqrt{2}-\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. The result is therefore

$$a+b+c=0$$